# Is there any evidence that Frank Dillane is signed for the next season of Fear the Walking Dead?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, the-walking-dead, fear-the-walking-dead

So far, my favorite character on *Fear the Walking Dead* is Nick Clark, played by the actor Frank Dillane.

> On tonight's episode, he was taken away by the military, and a short time later, Travis heard and saw gunfire in the distance.  The obvious implication is that Nick and the other people who were taken away by the army might have been killed, presumably because they were sick, or otherwise deemed to be useless and a drain on limited resources.

I know *The Walking Dead* well enough to realize that this is precisely what the producers want us to think, and they have shown quite the knack for misdirection throughout the history of *TWD*;  it should come as no surprise that they are employing similar methods in *FTWD*.

I noticed that the IMDB entry for *FTWD* lists most of the main cast members as being contracted for 7 episodes, which represents the six episodes of the current season, as well as the first episode of next season.  The dates listed for these actors are "2015-2016".  However, Frank Dillane's entry only lists six episodes, all of which are in 2015.

> I see two possible ways to interpret this:
>  1.  The producers are deliberately obfuscating the issue to keep the lid on who does and doesn't make it to season two, and Nick is alive and well (okay, maybe not "well", since he's a junkie wrestling with withdrawal, but still alive).
>  2.  Nick is really dead, and he really isn't going to be on the show next season.

The only way I can see to resolve this issue is by reference to any potential evidence that Dillane has signed a contract that includes next season.

### Has any such evidence surfaced?  Do we have any reason to believe that Nick will appear in the second season of *Fear the Walking Dead*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, he is going to be in Season 2.**

As of October 6<sup>th</sup> there is no "official" publication that states specifically that he is, however, [The Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/) has an article entitled ['Fear the Walking Dead' Boss Previews Faster Pace, Mix of Land and Sea in Season 2](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/fear-walking-dead-season-two-829585). In that article, which is almost entirely about season 2, [Dave Erickson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1129521/) states when speaking about Strand:

> He sees something in **Nick** he's responding to and **we'll find out more about what that is**, but there's something enigmatic about Strand.

**That is a very strong implication that he is indeed on Season 2.**